# Can I use midi without external speakers?

Tags: piano, midi, digital-piano

I bought the Thomann DP-26 and wanted to use a different sound. I can use a Midi output but can I play the midi sound on the speakers of the piano again, so i dont have to jse external speaker?

Comment: Isn't this what Thomann's customer service is for?

Comment: This is too unclear. What sound? From where? What are you using the Midi for? Are you recording the Midi & want to play it back with a different Midi voice? Are you using a VST or 'sound font' & want to play that sound through your piano speakers?

Comment: So you go midi out into another midi device. That then needs amp and speaker to be heard. There's no way to loop it back into the keyboard. that's not how midi works.

Comment: What you want to do used to be easy in the earlier days of midi  because you had mid out midi in cables. If you went out from the keyboard to the computer and used a separate wire to go back from the computer to the keyboard you could play back what you recorded through your keyboard again. It is unclear if usb midi connections on a newer keyboard accept the signal back to the computer. My guess is maybe some do but most don’t. You can always test it, just check settings to see if midi out is assigned to usb in your daw.

Answer (score 1):

I read on its web page:

> Connections: 2x headphones, MIDI out, USB MIDI, sustain, aux in/ out

USB MIDI does not imply an audio interface.  There is aux in, meaning that you can connect an external sound source like a Midi expander.

The description in the manual says:

> External audio devices via AUX IN
> Use the [AUX IN] socket to connect a, for example, CD or MP3 player to the digital
> piano. So you can playback music through the internal speakers of the digital piano
> and simultaneously play along to it. Plug one end of the audio cable into the [AUX IN]
> socket on the rear panel of the digital piano and the other end into the output of the
> respective audio device.

Given the listed examples, it would seem that this QIC socket likely takes a stereo signal similar to a headphone signal, so depending on just what kind of extender you use, you might need to use some adapter cable.

If you do the Midi expansion on a computer, you'll need some kind of audio interface to get the signal out in analog form, and you'll want to make sure that you do it with a low latency in order not to disrupt your playing (unless you are practising for playing a pneumatic organ that are notorious for latency).

If you use the USB MIDI connection, you'll likely create a ground loop together with the audio connection that may warrant breakup with a DI-like device because of creating digital noise and/or hum.  Using a good(!) USB MIDI interface instead on the 5-pin DIN would create optical isolation and thus also break up a ground loop, just on the MIDI side rather than on the audio side.  Many external soundcards do have an additional MIDI in/out and if you experience hum problems by using USB MIDI directly for hooking up with your computer, you might want to try that if you are using the soundcard for audio output anyway.